# Quartz Scheduler is not working when PC time changes manually

Tags: c#, winforms, quartz

### Having Trouble with Quartz when PC Time Changes Manually

I am using Quartz in my C# Windows Form project.

It is working well, but while the application is working 
I am changing PC time manually then scheduler goes off, 
not working anymore.

I have to change the time in a scheduled way.
        Is there a smart way to overcome this situation? 
        My working code looks like this;

```
public static class QuartzTimer
{
public static IScheduler _scheduler;
public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    _scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    _scheduler.Start(); //Schedular is starting here
    AddJob();           //My jobs are done in this method
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your reason of changing the computers time?

Comment: It is a 24 Hours working PC. PC time is corrected once a day through DNP3.0 protocol.

Comment: Is it corrected through your Application or from outside? And: Is the clock _that_ bad or do you need _really_ exact time for something?

Comment: When correcting through my program,I am stopping the schedular, set the time and restart the schedular. Now, I have to do it from outside.